# Char array pointer vs string refrence in params

Tags: c++, string, function, argument-passing

I often see the following structure, especially in constructors:

```
class::class(const string &filename)
{
}


class::class(const char * const filename)
{
}
```

By step-by-step debug, I found out the 2nd constructor is always called if I pass a hard-coded string.

Any idea:

1) Why the dual structure is used?

2) What is the speed difference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two constructors are needed because you can pass a `NULL` to your `MyClass::MyClass(const std::string &arg)`. Providing second constructor saves you from a silly crash.

For example, you write constructor for your class, and make it take a `const std::string &` so that you don't have to check any pointers to be valid if you'd be using `const char*`.
And everywhere in your code you're just using `std::string`s. At some point you (or another programmer) pass there a `const char*`. Here comes nice part of `std::string` - it has a constructor, which takes `char*`, and that's very good, apart from the fact, that `std::string a_string(NULL)` compiles without any problems, just doesn't work.

That's where a second constructor like you've shown comes handy:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const char* arg)
    : m_string(arg ? arg : "")
{}
```

and it will make a valid `std::string` object if you pass it a `NULL`.

In this case I don't think you'd need to worry about any speed. You could try measuring, although I'm afraid you'd be surprised with how little difference (if any) there would be.

EDIT: Just tried `std::string a_string(NULL);`, compiles just fine, and here's what happens when it is run on my machine (OS X + gcc 4.2.1) (I do recall I tried it on Windows some time ago, result was *very* similar if not exactly same):

`std::logic_error: basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid`

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies the matter!

Answer (score 1):

This is useful if the implementation deals with `const char*`s by itself, but is mostly called by `std::string` users. These can call using the `std::string` API, which usually just calls `c_str()` and dispatches to the `const char*` implementation. On the other side, if the caller does already have a c-string, no temporary or unneeded `std::string` needs to be constructed (which can be costly, for longer strings it's a heap allocation).

Also, I once used it to resolve the following case:

My interface took `std::string`'s, but had to be implemented in an external module, thus the STL binary versions of both the module AND the caller module had to match *exactly*, or it would have crashed (not really good for a portable library… ). So I changed the actual interface to use `const char*`, and added `std::string` overloads which I declared `inline`, so they weren't exported. It didn't break existing code, but resolved all my module boundary problems.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Why the dual structure is used?

The string reference version is required if std::string objects are to be used conveniently  as parametersm as there is no implicit conversion from a std::string to a const char const. The const char * const version is optional, as character arrays can implicitly be converted into std::strings, but it is more efficient, as no temporary std::string need be created.

```
2) What is the speed difference?
```

You will need to measure that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

They are offered basically for convenience. Some times, if you call C functions, you get char* pointers. Others, you get strings, so offering both constructors is just a convenience for the caller. As for the speed, both have virtually the same speed, as they both send a memory address to the constructor.

Comment: Same speed? Even if the constructor taking the string does contact a with a remote repository and downloads a chinese translation of War and Peace via Google Translation API via the repository, and the char* constructor just assigns a value? :P

Comment: If the original string is a C++ string, performance will be the same. If the original string is a C-style string (or a literal), then having only the std::string version will require creation of a temporary. My advice would be using C++ strings whenever necessary, but if you find a bottleneck in performance consider adding the extra C-style overload.